# Is it necessary to add an EJB module as a library in a Web module to inject session beans

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I created a new Java EE 6 Enterprise-Application in Netbeans 7.4. with Glassfish 4.0 application server. So I have three Projects:

```
EAR
EJB
WAR
```

when I inject session bean from the EJB module into the managed bean of Web(WAR) module, it generates the following error

```
WARNING:   /login.xhtml @16,131 value="#{loginBean.username}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'loginBean' resolved to null
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /login.xhtml @16,131 value="#{loginBean.username}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'loginBean' resolved to null
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.findImplicitConverter(InputRenderer.java:170)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.findConverter(InputRenderer.java:190)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.getConvertedValue(InputRenderer.java:196)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1046)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:976)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1249)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
at org.primefaces.component.layout.Layout.processValidators(Layout.java:246)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at filters.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:44)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'loginBean' resolved to null
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:174)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:86)
at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:201)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getType(WeldValueExpression.java:93)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:98)
... 51 more
```

And during deployment the Glassfish server also generates the following error

```
SEVERE:   Exception while loading the app
SEVERE:   Undeployment failed for context /ZTE-WMS-war
SEVERE:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/wms/sessions/UseraccountManager;
```

I wrote the managed bean class(LoginBean) as follows

```
package com.wms.managedbeans;

import com.wms.sessions.UseraccountManager;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

//@Named("loginBean")
@ManagedBean(name="loginBean")
@RequestScoped

public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String password;
private String message, username;
@EJB
private UseraccountManager uam;

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String uname) {
    this.username = uname;
}
public String getUser() {
    System.out.println(Util.getUserId());
    return Util.getUserId();
}
public String getUserType(){
    HttpSession session = Util.getSession();
    if ( session != null )
        return (String) session.getAttribute("userType");
    else
        return null;
}


public String login() {

    String userType = uam.validateUser(username, password);
    HttpSession session = Util.getSession();
    if (userType.equals("unknown")){
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                null,
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,
                "Invalid Login!",
                "Please Try Again!"));
        // invalidate session, and redirect to other pages
        //message = "Invalid Login. Please Try Again!";
       return "login";
    }
    else{
      // get Http Session and store username
      session.setAttribute("username", username);
      session.setAttribute("userType",userType);
      if (userType.equals("administrator")) 
        return "admin/adminHome?faces-redirect=true";
      else if(userType.equals("warehouseman"))
        return "WM/wmHome?faces-redirect=true"; 
      else if(userType.equals("employee"))
        return "emp/empHome?faces-redirect=true"; 
      else 
          return "man/manHome?faces-redirect=true";
    }
}

public String logout() {
  HttpSession session = Util.getSession();
  session.invalidate();
  return "/login?faces-redirect=true";
}
}
```

When I added the "EJB jar" into the WEB(WAR) module as a library it works perfectly.

Now my question is, is it mandatory to add the EJB jar as a library in-order to inject session beans into managed beans. if there is any other way(s) please help me

Comment: I think there is no possibility to use some technology provided by java-ee without including appropriate library to your project as dependency.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You don't want to include the EJB jar in the EAR?

Comment: @kolossus, I added the EJB jar as a library into the WAR(Web module). By right clicking on the WAR module -->Property--->library-->then I checked on the EJB jar.....So my question is. Is it mandatory to do so or is there any other way to inject the session bean inside the EJB module??